# Seguimiento de script en SQL Server Profiler

Tags: c#, sql, visual-foxpro

Porque cuando ejecuto este stored procedure, se comporta asi:

Desde C# pasa así

```
declare @p2 char(13)
set @p2='AGB17920'
exec sp_nuevo_codigo @CodGrupo='AGB',@vcodarticul=@p2 output
select @p2
```

En Visual Fox Pro pasa así:

```
declare @p4 varchar(8000)
set @p4=''
exec sp_executesql N'exec sp_nuevo_codigo @P1  @P2 OUTPUT ',N'@P1 varchar(3),@P2 varchar(8000) OUTPUT','AGB',@p4 output
select @p4
```

En Visual Fox Pro, es donde sale el error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@P2'.

Comment: El error es que en `sp_nuevo_codigo @P1  @P2 OUTPUT` falta una coma entre `@P1` y  `P2`, deberías copiar el código Visual Fox para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Que verguenzaaaa, medio día por esa coma sinverguenzaaaa